# Access Violation Exception in Custom Game Engine - PeekMessage() / imm32.dll

Tags: c++, windows, exception, game-engine

I've been struggling with a random exception that pops up when a key is pressed on the keyboard. The exception only occurs when a key is pressed. In some instances, it doesn't happen at all. In the instances where it happens, it always happens on the very first key press. I've tried pressing any random keys - that doesn't seem to matter. They all throw the exception.

This game engine has been under development for a long time - nearly 20 years. This means there is a ton of code (19MB). It also means that there are several older components, like Direct Input from 10 years ago. These older components will eventually be swapped out. I don't think this exception is related to Direct Input, but could be wrong. It definitely seems to be related to keyboard input and imm32.dll. But I can't figure out if the fault is within imm32.dll, or if I'm accidentally overwriting memory somewhere else.

I use custom memory debugging tools, and rarely encounter exceptions like this in my own code, but that doesn't mean this issue isn't coming from my code. I've tried using the Visual Studio Code Analysis tools, which took an enormous amount of time to compile, but found nothing wrong. I also ran some Windows repair tools related to imm32.dll, but no change.

I'm just looking for any advice or help to narrow this down to something I can fix. Debugging is often challenging, but this one is giving me a very hard time. I've googled this to death, and found nothing related. That tells me this is probably unique to my situation. Either I've fudged memory somewhere, or one of my Windows files has become corrupted. But these are just guesses.

Here is the exception screen shot, along with the call stack:
[image: Exception screen shot]

Here is the call stack in text form:

```
imm32.dll!ImmLockImeDpi()
imm32.dll!_ImmProcessKey@20()
user32.dll!___ClientImmProcessKey@4()
ntdll.dll!_KiUserCallbackDispatcher@12()
user32.dll!PeekMessageA()
* Kestarda.exe!MainFrame::UpdateMessages(int message_proc_limit=0)
Kestarda.exe!MainFrame::LifeCycle::Execute()
Kestarda.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * h_instance=0x00540000, HINSTANCE__ *  __formal=0x00000000, char * command_line=0x02ba4d74, int __formal=10)
Kestarda.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()
Kestarda.exe!WinMainCRTStartup()
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart()
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()
```

And here is the assembly from the exception point/function:

**imm32.dll!ImmLockImeDpi(void):**

```
75423E70  mov         edi,edi  
75423E72  push        ebp  
75423E73  mov         ebp,esp  
75423E75  cmp         byte ptr [_gfInitialized (7543A5A0h)],0  
75423E7C  je          ImmLockImeDpi+76h (75423EE6h)  
75423E7E  push        esi  
75423E7F  push        edi  
75423E80  push        offset _gcsImeDpi (7543A5C0h)  
75423E85  call        dword ptr [__imp__RtlEnterCriticalSection@4 (7543B268h)]  
75423E8B  mov         edi,dword ptr [ebp+8]  
75423E8E  mov         eax,edi  
75423E90  shr         eax,10h  
75423E93  and         eax,0F000h  
75423E98  cmp         eax,0E000h  
75423E9D  je          __SEH_epilog4+0FA8h (75426BE5h)  
75423EA3  mov         eax,1  
75423EA8  mov         esi,dword ptr [_gpImeDpi (7543AC30h)]  
75423EAE  test        esi,esi  
75423EB0  je          ImmLockImeDpi+63h (75423ED3h)  
75423EB2  cmp         dword ptr [esi+8],edi                <----- EXCEPTION
75423EB5  jne         ImmLockImeDpi+7Eh (75423EEEh)  
75423EB7  test        byte ptr [esi+50h],4  
75423EBB  je          ImmLockImeDpi+7Ah (75423EEAh)  
75423EBD  mov         ecx,1  
75423EC2  cmp         eax,ecx  
75423EC4  jne         ImmLockImeDpi+7Eh (75423EEEh)  
75423EC6  test        esi,esi  
75423EC8  je          ImmLockImeDpi+63h (75423ED3h)  
75423ECA  test        byte ptr [esi+50h],1  
75423ECE  jne         ImmLockImeDpi+86h (75423EF6h)  
75423ED0  inc         dword ptr [esi+4Ch]  
75423ED3  push        offset _gcsImeDpi (7543A5C0h)  
75423ED8  call        dword ptr [__imp__RtlLeaveCriticalSection@4 (7543B26Ch)]  
75423EDE  pop         edi  
75423EDF  mov         eax,esi  
75423EE1  pop         esi  
75423EE2  pop         ebp  
75423EE3  ret         4  
75423EE6  xor         eax,eax  
75423EE8  jmp         ImmLockImeDpi+72h (75423EE2h)  
75423EEA  xor         ecx,ecx  
75423EEC  jmp         ImmLockImeDpi+52h (75423EC2h)  
75423EEE  mov         esi,dword ptr [esi]  
75423EF0  test        esi,esi  
75423EF2  jne         ImmLockImeDpi+42h (75423EB2h)  
75423EF4  jmp         ImmLockImeDpi+56h (75423EC6h)  
75423EF6  xor         esi,esi  
75423EF8  jmp         ImmLockImeDpi+63h (75423ED3h)  
75423EFA  int         3  
75423EFB  int         3  
75423EFC  int         3  
75423EFD  int         3  
75423EFE  int         3  
75423EFF  int         3
```

Comment: Look at the local variables after the crash.  Is the this pointer valid or is msg the problem and somehow your stack is invalid.

Comment: If you compiled the engine code from source (which it sounds like you are) and aren't just linking to it I would probably rebuild the whole project with address sanitization enabled. It is a pretty good tool for tracking down most kinds of memory errors.

Comment: @floomby I had never heard of this tool. I'm checking it out now. Thanks!

Comment: @drescherjm All of the local variables in my UpdateMessages() function look normal, as far as I can tell. But I will look them over one more time to make sure.

Comment: If you find that either of those are 0xFEFEFF06 it could help determine what is happening.

Comment: FEFEFF06 = FEFEFEFE + 8, and FEFEFEFE is a heap sentinel value that means "using memory that has been freed". So maybe you freed memory that IME was using. A memory sanitizer may help find it. Or turn on app verifier with heap verification. Or use Time Travel Debugging to figure out where the FEFEFEFE came from.

Comment: That AddressSanitizer tool sounds pretty amazing, but the option appears to be completely missing from Visual Studio Community 2022 (preview). I loaded the project into VS 2019 and 2017 Professional, and the option seems to be missing from all of them. It is supposedly in Project properties - Config - C++ - General, at the bottom. Does anyone know how to enable this tool? Do I need to disable any other features first? I read through Microsoft descriptions, but nothing seems to match up.

Comment: So I changed related code to MSG msg = {}; to clear the structure before the PeekMessage() is called, then tested. It looks like the exception is occurring before any of my local variable data is touched. Everything was still cleared to zeroes. What I find strange is that even when I change a lot of code, compiler options, etc, the exception is always in this exact spot. I would expect memory fudging to be a little more random. But I guess it just depends.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)